# GetElement / P Class and ID Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

my code below 100% works in browser, all the buttons function how I want them to but when I imported this code into Electron to eventually run as a program the only button that works the way it should is the first one. Im under the understanding its because I have multiple ID's for paragraphs and I shouldn't. So in response to this I removed all the ID's, and changed the GetElementByID to GetElementsByClass. This didn't work and nothing works at the moment unless I reinsert ID's. Here is the original code with ID's

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>What Should I Draw</title>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    }

.demo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #008CBA;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 300%;
    }

.remo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #008CBA;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 300%;
    }

.temo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;
    }

.zemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }

.kemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }

.uemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }
.buttons {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Subject" onclick="getRandomArrayElements(3);" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Restriction" onclick="GetValue();" />
</div>
<p id="demo" class="demo"></p>
<p id="remo" class="remo"></p>



<script>

function getRandomArrayElements(count) {


var arr = ['Swamp','Tank','Claws','Flying Tank',

];
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
    while (i-- > min) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=shuffled.slice(min);
}

</script>

<div>

<script>

function GetValue()
{

var myArray = new Array("Steampunk","Horror","Cartoon","Anime","Cheesy",

);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("remo").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Type of Landscape" onclick="Landscape();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Man Made Element" onclick="Manmade();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Time of Day" onclick="Timeofday();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Weather" onclick="Weather();" />

<p id="kemo" class="kemo"></p>
<p id="uemo" class="uemo"></p>
<p id="zemo" class="zemo"></p>
<p id="temo" class="temo"></p>


</div>


<script>

function Weather()
{

var myArray = new Array("Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies",
"Partly Cloudy",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("temo").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

<div>

<script>

function Timeofday()
{

var myArray = new Array("Noon","Morning","Sunrise","Afternoon","Magic Hour","Sundown","Night","Twilight","Aurora","Late Night","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("zemo").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>
<div>
<script>

function Landscape()
{

var myArray = new Array("Canyon","Grand Canyon","Beach","Cliff","Mountain Range",

);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("kemo").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>
<div>
<script>

function Manmade()
{

var myArray = new Array("Cityscape","Futuristic Cityscape","Futuristic City","Futuristic Cityscape",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("uemo").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are all the changes I made to remove the ID's and replace them with classes denoted by **'s surrounding them. A Quick update from looking around, wrapping the getElementById("demo") with [0] gets the first button to work. How do I get the rest of them to work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>What Should I Draw</title>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    }

.demo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #008CBA;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 300%;
    }

.remo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #008CBA;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 300%;
    }

.temo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;
    }

.zemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }

.kemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }

.uemo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200%;

    }
.buttons {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Subject" onclick="getRandomArrayElements(3);" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Restriction" onclick="GetValue();" />
</div>
**<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="remo"></p>**



<script>

function getRandomArrayElements(count) {


var arr = ['Swamp','Tank','Claws','Flying Tank',

];
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
    while (i-- > min) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
document.**getElementsByClassName("demo")**.innerHTML=shuffled.slice(min);
}

</script>

<div>

<script>

function GetValue()
{

var myArray = new Array("Steampunk","Horror","Cartoon","Anime","Cheesy",

);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.**getElementsByClassName("remo")**.innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Type of Landscape" onclick="Landscape();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Man Made Element" onclick="Manmade();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Time of Day" onclick="Timeofday();" />
<input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Weather" onclick="Weather();" />

**<p class="kemo"></p>
<p class="uemo"></p>
<p class="zemo"></p>
<p class="temo"></p>**


</div>


<script>

function Weather()
{

var myArray = new Array("Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies","Clear Skies",
"Partly Cloudy",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.**getElementsByClassName("temo")**.innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

<div>

<script>

function Timeofday()
{

var myArray = new Array("Noon","Morning","Sunrise","Afternoon","Magic Hour","Sundown","Night","Twilight","Aurora","Late Night","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon","Noon",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.**getElementsByClassName("zemo")**.innerHTML=random;
}
</script>
<div>
<script>

function Landscape()
{

var myArray = new Array("Canyon","Grand Canyon","Beach","Cliff","Mountain Range",

);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

**document.getElementsByClassName("kemo")**.innerHTML=random;
}
</script>
<div>
<script>

function Manmade()
{

var myArray = new Array("Cityscape","Futuristic Cityscape","Futuristic City","Futuristic Cityscape",
);
var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

**document.getElementsByClassName("uemo")**.innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Element IDs _must be unique_. If you need elements to share an ID, use a class instead. Make sure to change `getElementById`...

Comment: What are the random `**` doing around your `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: Thats where im confused, in the second example where I removed ID's and went to classes something has gone wrong and I don't know why the buttons are no longer responding.

Comment: Sorry Wizard. those were just to denounce to you guys that that 2nd portion of coding's differences from the first. Anything with those is where changes have occured.

Comment: The only problem you had in the first one is the multiple id of btnSearch, your other id's were fine as they were unique to each element. The problem you face in the second one is that `getElementsByClass` returns an array like structure you cant just do `getElementsByClass("something").innerHTML`. You access the individual elements like `getElementsByClass("something")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: I have changed the ID's of the first one's btnSearch's and nothing has changed. The only button working still is the first.